# Profiling, detecting, and improving assignment performance?

Tags: python, profiling

I need to profile a script file. I decorated the function in question with `@profile` and used `kernprof.py -l -v scriptfile.py` to run the profiler, which gave me the stats listed below:

The assignment `_dict[date_kw][objekt_id]['subs_kaa']=item[kaa_subs]` takes 2.1µs, but is called about 8 million times (which is a fraction only and end ups with about 64 million) and the script has more of those assignments.

The target structure is a `dict(dict(dict(interger)))`.

Is there any option to speed this up, i.e. by copying the value differently?

```
Line# Hits    TimePerHit % Time Line Contents
108   7977576 16362872   2.1    6.3  _dict[date_kw][objekt_id]['subs_kaa']=item[kaa_subs]
109   7977576 16251240   2.0    6.3  _dict[date_kw][objekt_id]['subs_kad']=item[kad_subs]
110   7977576 15967840   2.0    6.1  _dict[date_kw][objekt_id]['subs_kip']=item[kip_subs]
```

Comment: Only a few pointers are copied in total, so that's not what's taking so much time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and replace your deep dict structure with a shallow one:

```
_dict[date_kw][objekt_id]['subs_kaa']=item[kaa_subs]  =>

_dict[ ( date_kw, objekt_id, 'subs_kaa' ) ]=item[kaa_subs]
```